# Set a default cell size while creating an excel document

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to create an excel sheet using Java. I have populated the data into the excel sheet by creating a Workbook object and creating a WritabeSheet object inside it. I want to set a default size to the cell in the WritableSheet object. How do I do that?

Here's the code snippet:

```
    private static void writeDataSheet(WritableSheet s, String str, int i) 
                                                                throws Exception{
        //Format the font
        WritableFont wf = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL, 
                                                          10, WritableFont.BOLD);
        WritableCellFormat cf = new WritableCellFormat(wf);
        cf.setWrap(true);       
        //Create label and write data to one cell of sheet
        Label l = new Label(0,i,str,cf);

        s.addCell(l);
        // I want to set a default size to the columns in the excel sheet here
    }
```

PS: The sheet.autoSizeColumn() does not work for WritableSheet!

Comment: Alternatively, is it possible to auto-expand each cell to fit the text written into it?

Comment: Did the answer work for you as it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I don't work on java & have not used jexcel.

Take a look at this method on `WriteableSheet` interface

```
public void setColumnView(int col,
                          CellView view)
```

ref: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/index.html

Here is how I think, it should work

```
CellView columnAView = new CellView();
columnAView.setAutoSize(true);

s.setColumnView(1, columnAView);
```

[`CellView` class reference](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/index.html)